# bundles in symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony1

whenever i add a feature i want to have all files (php, css, js, img etc) in one folder.

i know that this bundle feature will come with symfony 2.0 but i wonder if i can have all files in one folder/plugin in symfony 1.4 cause it seems that you have to have the js/css/img in web/ folder?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create/install a plugin, you can use the `symfony plugin:publish-assets` CLI command to copy all relevant web/ content to the correct location.